# デバッグ目的で、特定のクラス(もしくはメソッド)だけログを trace 出力したい

Tags: java, spring-boot

spring-boot を使って開発しています。特定のループで無限ループが発生しているようなので、何が起きているのかを把握するために、 logger で trace のログを仕込むことにしました。

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Processor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Processor.class);
    private process() {
        Object current = getCurrent();
        while (current != null) {
            logger.trace("The object is: {}", current);
            doProcess(current);
            current = getNext();
        }
    }
    // 略
}
```

ただ、問題は trace なので、そのまま実行すると、その他もろもろの trace で埋め尽くされてしまう気がしています。 一時的に、 info などにすればいいかもしれませんが、あちこち替えていって最後に戻し忘れたりするのはちょっと嫌だと考えました。

質問:

- spring-boot (でデフォルトで使用されている Logback) で、一時的に特定のクラスだけ trace 出力したいです。どうやったら手っ取り早くこれを実現できるでしょうか。

Comment: 特定のクラスだけ出力するという機能は無いかもしれません。ちょっと気になったんですが、無限ループの中でログを出力したら、大量にログが出力されることになります。注意して実行下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src/main/resources/logback.xml` に下記を追加することで、 spring-boot のデフォルトのロギング設定を拡張する形で、 `com.example.Processor` のログを TRACE 指定にできました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <logger name="com.example.Processor" level="trace" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Logbackであれば、設定ファイル「logback.xml」の`<logger>`タグにパッケージあるいはクラス名を指定してログレベルを個別指定できたと思います。

```
    <!-- 記述例(appender-ref "STDOUT"の詳細は割愛) -->
    <logger name="com.example.Processor" level="TRACE" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```

＃設定ファイル名は任意に指定できたと思うので、適宜読み替えて下さい。